# SQLAlchemy - relationship loading outside of query

Tags: sqlalchemy

We are in need of a way to load a relationship explicitly outside of a query and from an given set of cache values.

Our query is quite complicated and have a few explicit joinedLoad(..) option. Sadly using too much of those is really slowing the query as a whole and so we started using subqueryLoad(..) technique. However this does not work as expected, subqueryLoad is emitting a second query using a distinct clause on the first query (which is quite costly). What we are trying to do instead is to build a set of the relationship key we need to load once the first query has finished to run. Once we get back the result from this second query, how do we tell sqlalchemy to associate the result of the first query with the result of the second query ?

Here a snippet showing what we do for now (it works but it is quite ugly):

```
result = session.query(tableA).option(lazyload('*'), joinedload(tableB)).all()

relationship_keys = set()

for r in result:
    relationship_keys.add(r.tableC_id)

cache_relationships = session.query(tableC).filter(tableC.id.in_(relationship_keys)).all()

# link instance between them. This will not emit SQL as it will hit the cache previously loaded by using session.get(..)
[r.tableC_relationship for r in result]
```